# Scaling a TFrame

Tags: c++builder, vcl, c++builder-xe5

What is the correct procedure for Scaling a `TFrame` in C++Builder?

I am developing in PixelsPerInch=120 (aka. Windows font size 125%), but want my forms to work in PixelsPerInch=96 also (aka. default).

My main form loads fine: the VCL code to create a `TForm` includes a check of whether the design PPI differs from runtime PPI and it scales everything correctly at that point.

However when loading a `TFrame`, no automatic scaling occurs. So far as I have been able to discover, I have to manually call `Frame1->ScaleBy(M, D);`.

This *mostly* works however it has a bug (which I will describe below) so the result is a frame that is not scaled correctly.

What is the proper way to create a Frame and have it scale on load, like a Form does?

I am currently using the following:

```
// class member
TFrame *f;

// called just before Application->Run()
f = new TFrame(fMain);

int M = fMain->PixelsPerInch;
int D = 120;        // Matt's development

if ( M != D )
{    
    f->ScaleBy(M, D);
}
```

and then when I want to activate the frame, `f->Parent = fMain->Panel1;
        (*f)->ScaleBy(M, D);

I have also tried writing `f->Parent = fMain->Panel1;` before calling `ScaleBy`,  based on the theory that the Frame has controls using `ParentFont` and so on, so it might be better if this info is available during scaling; however this introduces other bugs.

---

The bug is that when calling `ScaleBy` on a Frame or a Form which has a `TLabel` which has `AutoSize=true` and `ParentFont=false` and `Anchors` including `akBottom`, then the Label is displayed much higher up on the window than it should be (maybe even off the top of the window).

I have tracked down the problem: the `TControl.ChangeScale` function includes a call to `ScaleMargins`, and the Margin property has an on-set trigger that ends up calling `AlignControls` for the parent form, which will move any controls with `AutoSize=true`.

By stepping through `Vcl.Controls.pas`, I see that my Label scales correctly at first , however when the next control (a radio group, it happens to be) is processed, the `AlignControls` is triggered, which changes my Label's `Top`.

The `AlignControls` function apparently can't handle the `TLabel` with the parameters I just described when called part-way through a rescaling operation.

I haven't firmly nailed down why, but I think it is because the parent Form or Frame has not yet been scaled (the `ScaleControls` function scales all the children before scaling the self), so it uses the form's old `Height` to calculate the actual `Top` that results from doing alignment to the bottom.

This effect is not triggered when loading the Form the first time, because the scaling code checks for `csLoading` component state and disables a whole lot of reactionary effects, including the call to `AlignControls`.

I haven't figured out why the bug is only triggered when `ParentFont=false`.

---

My current workaround is to include a line in the FormResize handler that manually realigns the Labels in question with another label that has `ParentFont=true` (and thus doesn't suffer from the bug).